# Shake: how to proceed when file name is not known a-priori

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I'm trying to set up `Shake` for building a web application. At the end of my build process I would like to rename the resulting `.js` and `.css` files according to a content hash (for cache busting purposes).

This means of course that I do not know the final names of the files which look something like `app-<hash>.min.js`.

Since the rule for building the final `index.html` needs to know
about the names, I would need something like

```
"index.html" %> \out -> do
  need [ "app-<hash>.min.js" ]
  ...
```

I've tried using a `phony` action along the lines of

```
"index.html" %> \out -> do
  need [ "revJsAndCssFiles" ]
  ...

phony "revJsAndCssFiles" $ do
  ... -- Hash and copy files to appropriate locations
```

This works but seems ugly since a `phony` action isn't supposed to
produce a file.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will the `index.html` need to refer to the hashed Javascript files? If so, one approach is:

```
"hash-js.txt" %> \out -> do
    src <- readFile' "app.min.js"
    let file = "app-" ++ show (hash src) ++ ".min.js"
    writeFile' file src
    writeFile' out file

"index.html" %> \out ->
    js <- readFile' "hash-js.txt"
    writeFile' out $ "<script src='" ++ js ++ ">"
```

Here you have a constantly named rule (`hash-js.txt`) which both produces the file you want (at an unknown location), and the name of that file (to a fixed location). That way when you need the file from `index.html` you both depend on it and get the resulting filename out, which is likely to be required.

This trick works equally well if you don't need the filename in `index.html` - then you just throw away the contents of the file - but it feels a bit uglier.